# What is the appropriate instance declaration of a subclasses?

Tags: java, inheritance, declaration

I have a class called `A` (the parent) and class `B` (subclass of A)

My question is what is the difference between the next lines :

```
 B b1 = new B();
 A b2 = new B();
```

I know that variables and methods in class B cannot be accessed in case of object `b2`

But how it works in memory ? what is the point of this? when to use each of them ?

Comment: It is called [polymorphism](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm).

Comment: @steeve Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason to use the superclass as the variable type:

Suppose you have an Animal class, and several subclasses like Elephant, Tiger, Giraffe, Hippo, etc.

Now you have another class called Zoo, which contains an Array called animals. Then you could have:

```
   animals[0] = new Tiger();
   anumals[1] = new Elephant();
```

But it is better to have animals declared as an ArrayList that can grow or shrink:

```
  animals.add( new Tiger() );
  animals.add( new Elephant() );
  animals.add( new Hippo() );
```

If a subclass has a method that is not an overload of a parent method, you can still access the subclass methods via the superclass variable by casting it:

```
 Animal a = animals.get(index);
 if ( a instanceof Tiger ) {
   ((Tiger)a).tigerMethod( ... );
 }
```

Not that this type of thing might not be the best design, but it illustrates the point.

Answer (score 0):

Object can have multiple Interfaces, let's say class B inherits from class A:
Class A can have 5 public methods,
Class B have additionaly 5 own public methods,
so in class B you see all 10 methods, whereas using class A you see only 5.

This is important, because in this way you can control which part (of the interface) of the class you give to other's (other programmers to use).

For egzample:

If you return from your public method a List<>, like:

```
public List<SomeClass> giveMeSomeList() {
   // both return statements are perfectly valid as return type is List<>
   return new LinkedList<SomeClass>();
   // return new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
}
```

then you are allowed to use any implementation of the List<> you have eg. You can chnage the implementation, that you construct and return an ArrayList<> or LinkedList<> from your method, but since the declared return type is List<> it makes no harm, no one will rely upon that you return concrete implementation (at least your'e not responsible for that), just that it will be a kind of List<>. But if you return from your public method very concrete implementation of a class, then your give others invitation to use and rely upon this concrete implementation, which in turn block the methos from the ability to chanage the underlying implementation without doing harm to other code.
So in this way (using apropriate types) you can make some restrictions on other programmers as to which methods they are allowed to use (the interface), and give you some freedom to change the implementation in the future - like in the exmple with lists.

When you use an interface in an method arguments type, you make the method more general, as it can be used with any subtype of the interface (or type).
Sometimes you just need very concrete implementation as an argument to your method, because without that you cannot do the needed operation, so you will rely on very concrete type to be supplied to your method, and declare that type in the arguments of the method.